# i want to download the facebook shorts of motivational category without url and access token

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to download the face book shorts of motivational category without URL and access token
I want to get the 10 shorts every time whenever I run the code. without login or creating account also. I just want to get the shorts or short video clips of motivational category.